Power of a continuous function
Recently, I have been studying continuous functions and my teacher tells me about the following:

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ is a continuous function and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ is a continuous function, then $f^{g}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty),$ defined by $f^{g}(x) = (f(x))^{g(x)}$, is also a continuous function.

After thinking about this a bit, I was thinking about taking composition of functions in order to prove this, but couldn’t able to show it, however, I can intuitively understand this is true, but I don’t know how to proceed.
Please help me.

Note that, if $f(x) \ne 0$,
$$
f(x)^{g(x)}
= \exp \left( \ln \left( f(x)^{g(x)} \right) \right)
= \exp \left( g(x) \ln(f(x)) \right)
$$
From other properties, the result is immediate:

The product of continuous functions is continuous
The composition of continuous functions is continuous
$\exp$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$
$\ln$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$

I'll let you fill in the gaps. In particular:

How do these work to get the desired result for $f(x)>0$?
Why does the equality not hold if $f(x)=0$? How might we finish our work for that case?


Consider $h(x)=\ln((f(x))^{g(x)})=g(x)\ln (f(x))$. Since $f^g=e^h$, it is sufficient to show that $h$ is continuous. Showing $\ln(f)$ is continuous should be trivial, so $h$ is continuous. It implies $f^g$ is continuous.
